# Disabling options in Autoselect material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, disable

I am trying to disable options in autocomplete of material ui based on a certain condition, I'm having an array and mapping it over a table , so every table row has a autocomplete , so whenever an option is selected in an table cell of autocomplete , that option should be disabled in the next table cell of autocomplete of the same row. I tried searching the [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) , but couldn't find an example similar to what I'm trying to achieve . There is a prop `getOptionDisabled` which is possible to disable an option if the option is array, I'm not sure if it can be used in my condition.

The options I'm passing is in `this.state.data`

Here is what I have tried so far https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-https-o7dz3

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-bush-05q4f?file=/src/App.js)

**Update** :
link of codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-https-o7dz3

Comment: I have updated the answer with the working link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable an option based on the value what you have done is correct only thing is you have not checked any value rather you have a text "Batch No."

Here is the [Documentation for disabled](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#disabled-options)

I just checked a value as an example 588 and I get desired result
[image]

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Please not it's not a full implementation, I shall try to give the sandbox for full implementation in the evening. For now it's the approach

I simply added an array (however we need multidimensional array to keep tract of the values that are chosen for each group)

[image]

And during handlechange event push the newly selected item to the array and remove old one (Please implement this)

[image]

Now add a function that would check if the item exists in this list

[image]

Finally bind this function to getOptionDisabled

[image]

Here's the final output
[image]

**Edit 2: working example**

[Here is the working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-framework-jwx3n) https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-framework-jwx3n

Comment: yes, but it will only work for 588 , i want to disable the option in next autocomplete based no the option selected in the previous autocomplete

Comment: What I meant was 588 is an example, you need to replace that with the logic that you want. What is the logic you want so that the items gets disabled?

Comment: i want to disable the option in next autocomplete(tablecell) based no the option selected in the previous autocomplete(tablecell)

Comment: Oh! ok. Now I get it. So what we need is the list of all selected items and every time anyone opens the autocomplete just check if that exits in the selected list

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was struck on it since days , this works but it has a down side , if I click on remove , the previous disabled option still stays up

Comment: so in removing func , i just used ```pop( )``` function and removing that variable from ```selectedList``` array

Comment: One more issue i found is that, when option is selected in 1st autocomplete and try changing the option for the same autocomplete, the previous option still stays disbaled

Comment: All these tings needs to be handled based on the those events. As I said, its approach. List down the events, and based on each events try pushing and popping items from the array that maintains the list of selected items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235126/discussion-between-jarivak-and-bharat).

Comment: Stills you are looking for full answer?

Comment: Next one hour I will post the solution with other events too

Comment: Have updated with the new link https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-framework-jwx3n